# Are all sizes of RSA keys possible?

Tags: rsa, key-size

I mistakenly thought that RSA keys could only be powers of two(1024, 2048, 4096 etc.) but a few days ago read about a 1536-bit and 1160-bit RSA key. I am wondering is it possible to have an RSA key of any bit length?(e.g 1025-bit RSA key, 1234-bit RSA key etc.) thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are RSA key sizes almost always a power of two?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/7854/18298)

Comment: Well, for one the smallest valid modulus would be 15, so there are no RSA keys with 3 bits or less.